# Cross Origin Policy & Fiddler JSON Debugging

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome, fiddler

I am working on developing a modern webapp using JSON data. I found the [following blog post](http://leefrancis.org/2011/07/08/fiddler-simple-development-server/) on using a tool called Fiddler to mock JSON data.

I am developing locally using Notepad++, and primarily testing on Chrome (I will eventually focus on more browsers). I have a main HTML file "index.html" and I use a file structure that looks like this:

```
index.html

    assets

        /js

        /css

        /img
```

I usually run my tests by launching the index.html file in Chrome from Notepad++. However, because I want to use the JSON "spoofing" capabilities of Fiddler, I run into the cross-origin policy restriction. I have Fiddler's autoresponder tool match a given URI (here, http://server.anywhere.com/test), and then return a JSON response pre-fabricated in a file.

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://server.anywhere.com/test. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.**

The code is just about as simple as it gets (jQuery 1.9.1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://server.anywhere.com/test", function(data) {
        $.each( data, function( i, item ) {
            console.log('Item number: ', i);
        });
    });
});
```

Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps a dev tool in Chrome?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You don't need another webserver for this, you can do it all with Fiddler's AutoResponder. Simply edit the rule in question to have an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header that contains the value of the origin of the requesting site.

If you need to perform a "non-simple" (CORS terminology) request, add a rule [like so](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/httpfiddler/D8Cxm4dfhkY/oFi6QGnOIWAJ):

`Method:OPTIONS PartialTargetURL` with an action of `*CORSPreflightAllow`

to the list of rules, *before* the rule returning the target response. This rule will cause Fiddler to response affirmatively to the preflighting request sent by the XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: Excellent to hear from a Fiddler guru! So, in your example I would do:Method: *CORSPreflightAllow EXACT:http://localhost:8000?

Comment: No, you'd do `Method:OPTIONS localhost:8000` with an action of `*CORSPreflightAllow`

Comment: I am using Fiddler Classic; and I am not sure how and where to implement that **rule**. I am assuming it would be added to the FiddlerScript under `static function OnPeekAtResponseHeaders(oSession: Session)`. I tried adding this under that rule: `oSession.oResponse["127.0.0.1:8090"] = "*CORSPreflightAllow";`; but it is not working. What am I missing?

Comment: @MeSo2: On the `AutoResponder` tab, create a new rule. (You could use FiddlerScript to implement a similar automatic response, but it's much more complicated)

Answer (score 0):

The bad news is that Chrome and Firefox don't allow cross domain calls for security reasons.

Option 1:
Use AJAX to call a local PHP file and in that file use "fopen" to get your data. (use if your web app is running on a server)

Option 2: Safari and Mobile devices will allow you to get the data with this request (use if your web app is running entirely on the client side)

```
    $.ajax({
     url: ('www.sitewherejsonis.com/data.json'),
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'json',
     beforeSend: function(xhr) {
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Base 64"; // if you need to authentificate
     },

     success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
       // do something
      }
     error: function(xhr, exception) {
     // catch error
     }
     });
```

Comment: I know that cross domain calls don't work, but this is a basic localhost test. Shouldn't I be able to somehow make Fiddler fake it?

Comment: It's a little bit more complicated than that. To answer your question I've spent days trying to go around this and even on a local host you can't. To be more exact your request is fine Fiddler responds but when the response ( callback) comes back Chrome stops you from viewing the data. It's to do with the safety policy for development you can search the web on how to disable the cross domain restriction in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working. I ended up using SimpleHTTPServer via the command line to launch the program. I then pointed the browser to localhost:8000 and things worked just fine. Using Fiddler2 and Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

As posted in another thread:

Try this - https://api.allowallorigin.com/restapi?url=www.sitewherejsonis.com/data.json

I have created this solution after trying multiple options. The other solution on the same line does the job but changes the JSON Data locations until one pays for it. Above service is free and will continue to remain free. If people find it useful, then I may put a home page and few google ads but otherwise it should continue to remain free for foreseeable future.

Sample Code:

```
    jPath.prototype.loadJSONDataFromUrl = function(_url, callback) {
    $.getJSON(_url, function(data) {
        $.fn.jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
    }).done(function(json){
        if( callback != null) {
            callback();
        }
    }).fail(function(){
        $.getJSON('https://api.allowallorigin.com/allorigin/restapi?url='+_url, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            $.fn.jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
        }).done(function(json){
            if( callback != null) {
                callback();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Fiddler2
Enable Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS > Decrypt HTTPS traffic and install the local Root Cert
Go to Rules > Customize Rules... or edit the CustomRules.js file in %USERPROFILE%/Documents/Fiddler2/Scripts or similar

Add the following near the top, next to the other RulesOption declarations:

```
public static RulesOption("Force CORS")
var m_ForceCORS: boolean = true;

Add the following at the end of the OnBeforeRequest method:

// If it's an OPTIONS request, fake the response and return w/e the client expects.
// NOTE: Methods and Headers are hardcoded. Modify as needed.


if (m_ForceCORS && oSession.oRequest.headers.HTTPMethod == "OPTIONS") { 
    oSession.utilCreateResponseAndBypassServer();
    
    oSession.oResponse.headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", oSession.oRequest.headers["Origin"]) ;
    oSession.oResponse.headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");          
    oSession.oResponse.headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, Csrf-Token, X-Requested-With, cloudSession, WbeSession, Cookie");
    oSession.oResponse.headers.Add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
    oSession.oResponse.headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    
    oSession.responseCode = 200;
}


Add the following at the end of the OnBeforeResponse method:

// Also add the headers to any real response with an "Origin:" header set

// Again, everything is hardcoded. Modify as needed.

// You could also .Remove() the header and .Add("$header_name", oSession.oRequest.headers["$header_name"])

// to mirrors the values given in the request.

if (m_ForceCORS && oSession.oRequest.headers.Exists("Origin")) 
{
    oSession.oResponse.headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
    oSession.oResponse.headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", oSession.oRequest.headers["Origin"]) ;
    
    oSession.oResponse.headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Methods");
    oSession.oResponse.headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    
    oSession.oResponse.headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Headers"); 
    oSession.oResponse.headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, Accept, Csrf-Token, X-Requested-With, cloudSession, WbeSession, Cookie");
    
    oSession.oResponse.headers.Remove("Access-Control-Max-Age");
    oSession.oResponse.headers.Add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
    
    oSession.oResponse.headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials");
    oSession.oResponse.headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
     
    // if (oSession.oRequest.headers.Exists("Cookie")) {
        // oSession.oResponse.headers.Remove("Set-Cookie");
        // oSession.oResponse.headers.Add("Set-Cookie", oSession.oRequest.headers["Cookie"]);
    // }
}
```