# Fiddler local file with cors

Tags: file, cors, response, local, fiddler

Im trying to debug an api that returns some information based of the localization of the user, in a local file I have saved the JSON structure, but when I try to load it give me CORS error. How can I add CORS to my local file?

I have tried this answer but doesn't works for me: [Cross Origin Policy & Fiddler JSON Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249740/cross-origin-policy-fiddler-json-debugging)

[image: Fiddler Rules]

Comment: What's the exact CORS error that you get? What does your code look like? What URL are you using? Do you see the `OPTIONS` preflight request in Fiddler?

Comment: @EricLaw I got the following error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load service.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'service.com'; is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404. 

My code is just an ajax with jquery with datatype json, using jsonp is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this, my final solution was mount a local server with xampp and create a php file that adds the headers and returns the json that I wanted:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
    header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo '{"key":"value"}'
?>
```